# Unable to load class grails.plugins.rendering.image.ImageRenderingService Grails 4 Rendering:2.03

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy

I am trying to use the plugin rendering:2.0.3 in grails 4 but i get the compilation error:

```
Unable to load class grails.plugins.rendering.image.ImageRenderingService
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to add the missing clasess in the file build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.xhtmlrenderer', name: 'flying-saucer-core', version: '9.1.6' //class org.xhtmlrenderer.simple.Graphics2DRenderer
compile group: 'io.github.msalaslo', name: 'flying-saucer-pdf', version: '9.1.20' //class org/xhtmlrenderer/pdf/ITextRenderer
compile 'org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.3'
```

thanks to the website for providing it
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-core/9.1.8/source-code/org/xhtmlrenderer/simple/Graphics2DRenderer.java